# No division in numerical differentiaton algorithm

Tags: algorithm, fpga, differentiation

I am trying to understand an algorithm that evaluates the speed of a moving element. The position sensors are sampled with varying but rather big speed (from 16MSPS to 24MSPS) and the speed is calculated as a simple difference between the last two values.

The formula for the speed is then `v = f(x_(n+1)) - f(x_n)` , and according to all numerical approaches i was expecting`v = (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h`

I don't really understand why the division is omitted. Under what circumstances can the division be ignored?

This system is implemented on a FPGA.

Comment: The varying rate of sampling is valid if we consider one given sensor only? Is the speed value further processed, like smoothed? How often the sampling speed varies (if it does)?

Comment: The division can be ignored if the time (h) is equal to 1 unit.

Comment: @user188421 the sampling speed is set up on the device before the measurements, but it is not saved in any variable, or used later for any calculations.
The speed value is further smoothed with a moving average filter (low pass filter), and then oversampled and undersampled for a better signal noise ratio..

Comment: @samthegolden yes, that is clear. Actually the samples compared in the formula are taken 1 period apart, so it would make sense to omit the division. The problem is the sampling speed may be set to a different value, and as the current sampling speed is never being saved to any variable I can't see how this information can help with estitmating the value of the speed of the sensor...

Comment: The speed doesn't matter, only the position. Since you know the position in two different moments, and the period given is 1, then you just subtract one from the other.

Comment: @samthegolden I am having problems with understanding exactly this... After subtracting one from another I get the change in position over one period - this is clear. However to be able to define the speed I need to know how big that period of time it was, to take this two samples. It could have been anything within the given setup possibilities (16 to 24MSPS). And this is the information I am missing in this unit.

Comment: No. The change in position is the same of the speed, if the time delta is 1!

Comment: I know nothing about FPGAs, but is there any performance/bandwidth/whatever constraint? Are the measurements noisy? How are the speed value used? Maybe it's just checked if it's below/above a somewhat arbitrary threshold, where the actual MSPS doesn't really count?

Answer (score 0):

It can be ignored when `h` is 1 as divide by 1 is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to many comments I was able to understand the problem:

The unit calculating the speed doesn't need to know the time period. By subtracting the next sampled value from the previous one, it produces output values. These values represent a function, that is is linearly dependent on the speed. One way to understand this is, that this output is  kind of 'speed without units'. The output can be than further manipulated (oversampled, undersampled) to achieve desired signal quality.

To able to determine the speed in some exact units (like m/s) at least the sampling frequency has to be given. In case of rotational movement also other constants are needed, such as the radius of the axis where the sensor is mounted, etc. This happens at some later point.